# Maths and physics agreement

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, models

This might be a semi-philosophical question - sometimes when we solve a physics problem, the maths gives solutions that are tossed out as "non-physical", and we keep only the solutions that make physical sense.

There are situations where the maths yields solutions that were not thought about previously, or yield valuable predictions that turn out to be observed later.

Shouldn't we require the maths to yield exactly and only physical solutions for it to be truthful? Aren't those extra solutions a sign that something is amiss with the equations we set up?

What if there were other ways to formulate the problems that didn't lead to solutions that must be thrown away? Wouldn't that be desirable? Maybe the fact that we have to throw away some solutions in some cases is an indication that the initial formulation was in fact, ever so slightly incomplete or wrong?

Another way to look at this question, is that when we have 2 models describing the same phenomenon, we choose either the simpler one, or the one that also explains other phenomena. Do spurious solutions ever enter into that choice? Should they?

Has there been any thinking about that by physicists? What is the position of famous physicists about these spurious solutions? Do you know of references that would touch on that topic?

Comment: There is usually more than one way to mathematically represent a physical phenomenon.  The fact that one choice of mathematical solution leads to "spurious" or trivial solutions does not invalidate the solutions that are physically realizable, especially if that particular mathematical approach most closely approximates the physical phenomenon in question.

Comment: @DavidWhite - yes - where I was going with this question is to ask whether among all mathematical representations of the same physical phenomenon, shouldn't we prefer the one that has the less - or no - spurious solutions? The "error" I talk about is not in the valid solutions, but in the initial formulation - I'm asking whether seeing spurious solutions is not a signal that the initial formulation is "not the right one", even if it does lead to valid solutions.

Comment: In my opinion, Occam's razor applies.  Use the simplest mathematical model that explains the observations, even if there are spurious or trivial solutions that are rejected.

Comment: @DavidWhite - ok that's definitely a good option - but what do we make of the fact that sometimes the spurious solutions are productive, i.e. they end pointing to some new physics, and sometimes they are not (if I understand correctly)? Isn't that troubling? Or, what if the right thing to do was to give up Occam's razor in the hope of getting more productive spurious solutions? Finally, is Occam's razor "in nature"? Maybe it's not?

Comment: Don't forget maths is the description of reality, and not is not the reality itself. There's no reason at all a priori that we should be lucky enough to have the two match up so well. Once you've accepted that, that sometimes a model gives an extra solution shouldn't be a problem. And since there's no expectation of maths=reality, there may not be a better/perfect model

Comment: @Frank, I agree with the comments from CDCM.

Comment: Yes absolutely - on the other hand, I feel modern maths is pliable enough that we should be able to do "anything" with it. It's not so much that maths should conform to reality, as that maths is flexible enough and can contort enough, in my opinion. It's not "hard" to create a new type of space of functions if Hilbert spaces are not adequate anymore - because the only constraint on maths is in fact non-contradiction. So, can't we use/invent maths that perfectly models what we need and is free of spurious solutions?

Comment: @Frank, you are free to do so at your leisure.  However, I don't see the utility in spending a whole lot of time to "reinvent a very slightly better wheel".

Comment: My worry is that if the initial model leads to spurious solutions, although it does work perfectly now for one phenomenon and we can be happy with that, the spurious solutions could be a signal that the model in fact contains errors, which would come back to bite us later, maybe as a blocker to put several models together.

Comment: There is a long history of asking about possibly interpretations of "unphysical" solutions to particular problems—for instance the Wheeler-Feynman absorber theory  is an attempt at interpreting the advanced wave solutions in E*M and various quantum mechanical theories have tried to build on the same ideas. But it is pretty rare for "non-physical" (as opposed to "not consistent with our initial conditions") solutions to have a good interpretation.

Comment: @Frank, I'll add (hopefully) one last comment that may satisfy you.  For the example of displacement, velocity, and constant acceleration, there is a very strong calculus relationship between all of these variables, such that displacement is a quadratic function of time.  Due to this, the associated mathematical radical in a displacement vs. time solution, will lead to two answers, with only one answer being considered "real".  Despite the "non-real" answer, very few people would argue for another mathematical approach, due to all the strong math relationships involved in this problem.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I believe my answer had addressed precisely the example you just gave.

Comment: I agree with all of the above - but those non real solutions could be worth thinking about in terms of how physics uses maths, or what the relationship is between maths and physics. Also, your case seems to be the same as what stafusa was mentioning below (nothing wrong, just commenting).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When "unphysical" solutions are not actually unphysical](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23030)

Answer (score 2):

Physical constraints are mathematically expressible. So in principle, if one wants to, they can be imposed from the outset, instead of at the end, in an apparently handwavy way.

For example, if $d$ is a distance, you can either:

- define it sloppily as $d\in \mathbb{R}$; or
- define it better, as $d\in \mathbb{R^+}$.

In the sloppy case, if you find out that $d$ satisfies
\begin{equation} d^2=9, \tag{1} \label{eq1}\end{equation}
then you'll obtain that $d=\pm3$ and you'll have to argue that, since a negative distance doesn't make sense, you can discard $d=-3$ and are left with $d=3.$

While, with the second definition, $d=-3$ doesn't even make sense ($d$ is non-negative) and doesn't arise as a solution to Eq. \eqref{eq1}, which has a single solution:

$$d=3.$$

Comment: you are on to something, and this is what I'm trying to think about: is it always possible, and shouldn't we require, that we express the model more carefully, so as not to have to remove solutions at the end? But is it always possible?

Comment: @Frank, In some branches of physics, I'd say it's always possible, if we don't demand unreasonable mathematical rigor, but I don't know about those branches that use more advanced, intractable math, such as QFT, string theory and the like. Even when it's possible, it would often be way too cumbersome to state at the start all the implicit constraints that might eventually turn out to be relevant.

Comment: @Frank, Remember also that even mathematics itself is thought to be non-axiomatizable, so there's certainly a limit to the level of rigor we can try to demand from a physical theory.

Comment: But the problem in my mind, is that something feels unreliable if we have to discard some solutions. If the maths always yielded exactly physical solutions, it feels it would be more reliable - either the maths would be more reliable, or the initial model would be more reliable, or both together. What if we had a model and maths derivations that yielded only unphysical solutions and we discarded them all, if in fact, one of them was pointing to some new physics?

Comment: @Frank, Yes, I know it's not about mathematical rigor, at least per se, it is about "descriptive rigor". So we have two types of rigor here: the mathematical one, and the one that requires that we make every single physical assumption explicit and impose it from the start... Yes, I think that could be grounds for discovery: if even after imposing all physical constraints you're aware of, you end up with unphysical solutions, either there are constraints you're unaware of, or the apparently unphysical solutions might not be so.